# Updating a msi application like clickOnce

Tags: windows-installer, installation, clickonce, gac, updating

I have developed a desktop application, which needs to install some DLL in client's GAC, so I distributed it to my clients as a MSI installer.

However, every time i publish a new version, the client has to download it manually and reinstall it. I was wondering if there is not a better way to distribute it.

Something like ClickOnce. On a ClickOnce distribution, when the users opens the app, it automatically detects that I have published a new version, downloading and installing it before opening the app.

However in a ClickOnce distribution I cannot install dll in client's GAC, so i cannot use it. Is there any way to distribute my app with these 2 requisites?

1. Install DLL in client GAC
2. Automatically updated when i published a new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite MSI being superior to ClickOnce in almost every way, auto updating pattern is the killer feature that MSI was never given a native solution for.  You have to implement this infrastructure yourself or leverage one from a vendor such as InstallShield or others.  You need a number of pieces such as a webservice to serve up the updates, a windows service to download and elevate the packages and a client side to quit the app, perform the install and restart the app.

Comment: @ChrisophetPainter Thanks for your comment. I was trying to avoid to create it by my own, but after some days looking for an alternative solution, i came to the same conclusion as you explain in your comment.

Comment: Yes, it's not trivial.  I've been contemplating starting an open source project but haven't gotten around to it yet